# What is "download-new.com"?

Tags: malware

This strange site came up as the second result in a google search for `itunes`.

http://download-new.com/apple-itunes/

(Although the url in the result read `itunes.download-new.com`.)

Embarrassingly, I downloaded and ran the "iTunes_Setup.exe" from them (I was stupidly trying to work on two computers at once and was barely paying attention, okay >_< ).

I immediately noticed it looked *weird*, and hit "Decline" on a series of "Offers"...

`appwiz.cpl` says no *programs* were installed today, but...

I can't find any third-party information on them, and the result I got there from no longer shows up when I repeat the google search.

Do I have a problem here?

Comment: If you Google "is this website safe" you find many reputation checkers like https://safeweb.norton.com/ or http://secureurlchecker.appspot.com/ where you can enter the suspect URL. Read the results carefully - i.e. how these websites come to their safe/unsafe conclusions.

Comment: It would be best to format both computers.

Comment: Its what you suspect.  A fake website that attempts to install ad-ware on your machine.

Comment: This is what it looks like. In my experience, the linked installer installs at least 6 or 7 pieces of crapware. ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/98iId.jpg)

Comment: from what i can see, its an advertisement, meaning it would appear first as they paid to have it on top

Answer (score 14):

I uploaded the file to [virustotal.com](http://virustotal.com) and found [these](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/624daa053ff589285a939b1b4d8e28af8876581ba05e45a0decbca2a3783a1df/analysis/1377834272/) results.  The sha256 hash of this file is: 624daa053ff589285a939b1b4d8e28af8876581ba05e45a0decbca2a3783a1df.

One of the scanners found "Win32.SuspectCrc" which appears to be a trojan.  And another scanner had found "a variant of Win32/Toolbar.MyWebSearch.S" which appears to be adware.

We probably don't need to look any further into this as these are a good indication of bad software.  There is a potential that these results are a false positive.

It looks like a software which includes a bunch of adware to make money and sell statistics.  Maybe not harmful, but you probably want to make sure you remove it.

Answer (score 3):

First check whether your search is hijacked. I'm not seeing that result when I searched `itunes`.

[image: Google search results for 'itunes']

Comment: The fact that your search results are different doesn't say much nowadays. Google tailors search results to your geographical location and search history.

Comment: But apple.com is one of the top 50 websites in the world.So I dont think they will go down in ranking due to locality.Also I didn't heard about product itunes other than apple itunes.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at http://download-new.com/learn you see it is some "We have this great downloader" website that indeed packs browser add-ons (currently 4).

There's not much useful info to find in their [terms of use](http://download-new.com/terms) or [privacy statement](http://download-new.com/privacy). You need a fine comb to determine from these what they're up to or what they actually do.

I see their URL in cached search results (e.g. at reference.com), so they manage to end up in search results - but the high ranking you see remains strange.